# Is there a viable conversion of void* from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, void-pointers

I am using a callback from C# to C++ using the function `rVDACQ_Connect` which returns a struct, I know I have the struct in correct format as I have tested the struct seperately. The function takes the parameters:
C++

```
tVDACQ_CallBackRec* (_stdcall* rVDACQ_Connect)(int, tVDACQ_CallBackProc, void*, short*, int);
```

With `tVDACQ_CallBackRec` being the returned struct.

What I want to know is the equivalent parameter types would be in C#.

```
tVDACQ_CallBackRec VDACQ_Connect(int i, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] tVDACQ_CallBackProc proc, IntPtr n, IntPtr[] buffer, int j)
```

Is what I have already. I have tried using IntPtr as the C++ portion that uses the function uses the keyword `this` for the `void*` parameter, and using `IntPtr` returned an error, being 'Method's type is not PInvoke Compatible'.

Part of the issue could also be the `short*` as when the paramter is passed into the function in the C++ code a `short[]` gets used, hence the reason for the `IntPtr[]`.

I would expect the struct to be returned, but I could also change the return type to be `IntPtr` and then do `Marshal.PtrToStructure`.

Comment: Even in C++ using `void*` instead of a concrete type is frowned upon. What does this `void*` point to?

Comment: The C++ isn't my code, it is sample code that I obtained for a device that I am trying to replicate some features in C# using callbacks and this is one of them. As far as I'm aware ```void*``` points to a dialogue box, as the parameter used is ```this```. So the image will appear in the dialogue box.

Comment: A void* is not unusual in a C function signature to make it easy to use in C++ code.  Makes it a lot easier to implement the callback as a C++ instance function.  But you have no use for that, the delegate you pass as the 2nd argument already takes care of it.  You do need to fix the IntPtr[], it is not a substitute for short*.  It is either IntPtr or short[], the short[] array can only work if it tells you about the size of the array.  Possibly the last parameter, use SizeParamIndex in the declaration.  Do show sample code to avoid guesses.